# Find largest square submatrix

Tags: c#, math, matrix, submatrix

I'm trying to find the largest square submatrix with same digits from matrix that can contain different numbers

I've found some answers that seems to be the same to this problem, but there weren't any with square submatrix

```
    int[,] dp = new int[a.GetLength(0), a.GetLength(1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                dp[i, j] = 1;
            else
            {
                if (a[i, j] == a[i - 1, j] &&
                    a[i, j] == a[i, j - 1] &&
                    a[i, j] == a[i - 1, j - 1])
                {
                    dp[i, j] = (dp[i - 1, j] > dp[i, j - 1] &&
                                dp[i - 1, j] > dp[i - 1, j - 1] + 1) ?
                                                        dp[i - 1, j] :
                                (dp[i, j - 1] > dp[i - 1, j] &&
                                 dp[i, j - 1] > dp[i - 1, j - 1] + 1) ?
                                                         dp[i, j - 1] :
                                                  dp[i - 1, j - 1] + 1;
                }
                else dp[i, j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

               {{7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7},
                {7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7},
                {7, 7, 1, 7, 7, 7},
                {7, 7, 3, 7, 9, 7},
                {1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 7},
                {7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7}}; I expect to get the top right 3x3 submatrix containing 7's
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is working almost correctly, you should only change the condition when the values of the previous numbers are equals.

```
    dp[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(dp[i - 1, j], dp[i, j - 1]), dp[i - 1, j - 1]) + 1;
```

This way you will have the next solution:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2,2,2
1,1,1,1,2,3
1,2,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Every number represents if there is a submatrix with the previous numbers, looking top and left. So the biggest submatrix is the one with the 3, starting in position (0,4) and ending in (2,6).